# Java JSF: How to pass a model of type List<T> to the view?

Tags: java, jsf

**BACKGROUND**

I am learning Java and currently on JSF. I come from an ASP.NET MVC background and have only recently been exposed to the Java world, so be gentle ;)

**PROBLEM**

I can't quite figure out how to get a model (which is of `List<T>`) into the JSF view. What I did when recently learning Struts was the following:

1. Created a Servlet like this:

   `@WebServlet(name = "ViewProductsServlet", urlPatterns = {"/ViewProductsServlet"})`

   `public class ViewProductsServlet extends HttpServlet {`

   ```
       protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
               throws ServletException, IOException {

           ProductRepository repository = new ProductRepository();
           List<Product> model = repository.getAll();
           request.setAttribute("model", model);
           request.getRequestDispatcher("/viewProducts.jsp").forward(request, response);
       }
   ```
2. Linked to the view products page like this:

`<html:link forward="viewProducts" styleClass="btn btn-primary">View Products</html:link>`

1. In the view, I got the model like this:

   `<%
       List<Product> model = (List<Product>)request.getAttribute("model");
   %>`

and then I just iterated over the items with JSTL tags.. not sure if that was the "correct" way to do it, but it worked..

Now for the JSF stuff, I am trying to take a similar approach but I noticed that the `<% %>` tags don't work in xhtml pages. Fair enough, but then how do I pass a collection to a page so I can display the items in a table/grid?

**EDIT**

Thanks to Sanjeevi.V, I can see that I am supposed to use the `h:dataTable` tag. However, it is not displaying data. Here is my code:

MODEL/Manage Bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class EmployeeCollection {
    private List<Employee> items;

    public List<Employee> getItems() {
        if (items == null) {
            EmployeeRepository repository = new EmployeeRepository();
            items = repository.getAll();
        }

        return items;
    }
}
```

View Markup:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span8 offset2">
                    <h:dataTable class="table table-striped" value="#{EmployeeCollection.items}" var="item">
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">First Name</f:facet>
                            #{item.getFirstName()}
                        </h:column>
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">Last Name</f:facet>
                            #{item.getLastName()}
                        </h:column>
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">Date of Birth</f:facet>
                            #{item.getDateOfBirth().toString()}
                        </h:column>
                    </h:dataTable>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I tried to follow that tutorial, so I'm not sure where I am going wrong. Personally, I don't understand how it could work.. how does the EmployeeCollection bean get wired up? Is it because it's got `@SessionScoped` that there is only ever one per session and so will use that? Even so, at the time of running, it would be a null object. What am I missing here? How can I make this work? I do indeed have rows in the database, so don't ask about that.  :)

Comment: Try using `<h:outputText value="#{item.getFirstName()}" />` instead of only `#{item.getFirstName()}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code,

Managed Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "bean")
@SessionScoped
public class Bean {
private List<Integer> numList;

public List<Integer> getNumList() {
    return numList;
}

public void setNumList(List<Integer> numList) {
    this.numList = numList;
}

public Bean() {
    numList=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        numList.add((int)(Math.random()*100));
    }
}

}
```

Markup:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.numList}" var="num">
  <h:column><h:outputText value="#{num}"/></h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

source : http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-datatable-example/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Please see my latest edit though.. if you can help, I'll mark you as answered. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
value="#{EmployeeCollection.items}"
```

camelcase starts small try

```
value="#{employeeCollection.items}"
```

Comment: Thanks, Udo. This helped, so you get an upvote from me. But answer goes to Sanjeev as he answered first and gave most of what I needed.  :)

Comment: Matt, Sanjeevi didn't answer your question. He just told that you need a good tutorial and pasted a link. His whole answer is worthless. You'd have to click the link and figure it out at your own in order to find the right answer to the question.